# window.addEventListener not updating state on route change when scrollY is not 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am adding `class` to  a `header` via `setState` using `addEventListener` in `componentDidMount`. The `state` of `scrolling` is set to `false` at `0` of `scrollY` and upon scroll, the `state` is updated to `true` and a `class` is added.

As an example

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = () => {
  if (window.scrollY === 0 && this.state.scrolling === true) {
    this.setState({ scrolling: false });
  } else if (window.scrollY !== 0 && this.state.scrolling !== true) {
    this.setState({ scrolling: true });
  }
};
```

within a GatsbyJS `layout`. It works perfectly between pages and templates when the user is returned to the top of the page.

However, on some occasions for example the `route` change via a `modal` or the user hits back on the browser the action is keep the previous `scrollY` position.

In this circumstance `scrollY` is not `0` but the `state` of `scrolling` is still showing `false`. I imagine this is because even though `scrollY` is showing the actual position, `state` `scrolling` is initially `false` until the user scrolls. This is portrayed in the `console`

How can I ensure that on route change, the `state` `scrolling` is updated to `true` if `scrollY` is not `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your `handleScroll` method once upon instantiation to capture the initial state. Right now you're relying on the scroll position being at the very top, but as you've found, going back in history results in a different initial state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  this.handleScroll();
}
```

Comment: Oh my, was that simple and makes such sense. Should this also be within `componentDidUnmount`?

Comment: Nope you don't need to clean up local variables, much less update their values before they go out of scope.